# CD 4504B from 12 V digital to 5 V digital level shifting

Tags: arduino, level-shifting

I need to translate 12 V / 1 mA to Arduino UNO digital input.

Is CD4504B a good choice? Because I already have one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you could use that, but you'd have to make sure the '12V' input has no transients that exceed 20V or so, depending on the exact part number, or add a series resistor such as 10K to the 12V input.

For a single input, you could use an NPN BJT with a couple resistors on it, which can be pretty much bulletproof (inverts the signal), and even more so if you add a diode from base to emitter. Or even use an optoisolator, which provides even more protection.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnHOsx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 12 V Signal coming from the sensor. It some kind of 9600 seriele connection. MAX 232 would be great here but i dont have one. Only as receiver for arduino. I am little bit confusing with 4504 with Vdd and Vcc. In my case i should put 12 V on Vcc, and 5 V on Vdd?

Comment: Yes, 12V on Vcc and 5V on Vdd. If it's actually RS232 it will go minus and the 4504 will not like that.